# What is best free IDE for MIPS assembly?

Tags: assembly, ide, mips

Anybody know what IDE for MIPS assembly has code assistant, visualization ... ?

Answer (score 9):

[MARS MIPS Simulator](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/).

From the site:

> MARS is a lightweight interactive development environment (IDE) for programming in MIPS assembly language, intended for educational-level use with Patterson and Hennessy's Computer Organization and Design.

Comment: i just wanted to say its an assembler not an IDE !